# How do I access an element inside a style programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, coding-style

I have a WPF button style below:

```xml
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
                    <Border Name="container" Background="{Binding Background}" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontSize="{Binding TextSize}" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="overlay" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="overlay" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                        <Setter TargetName="overlay" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that, although all of the buttons of my application have the same style,  some of them need to have a border around it. Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to access the container border of my style to set its thickness and color? If so how can I do this?

Edit:

I've mixed the suggestions of madd0 and Josh and created a DataTrigger inside my style with a binding to a property that tells me if the button should or should not have a border.

The final code is below:

```
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
                    <Border Name="container" Background="{Binding Background}" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontSize="{Binding TextSize}" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="overlay" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasBorder}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="container" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding BorderThickness}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="container" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="overlay" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                        <Setter TargetName="overlay" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thank you all for your help,
Komyg

Comment: what is it that determines whether the border should appear or not? it would be cleaner if you used triggers to make such a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you extend the Button class and give it a new boolean DependencyProperty, essentially all you need to do is give your Border a name, then in ControlTemplate.Triggers, Trigger off that boolean property to make the border as you need it in your special cases.

It would be similar to what you already have with the IsPressed ControlTemplate trigger.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to do this using a property from the data binding? This way instead of instantiating the class I would just create a property inside the DataContext class. Also does this property has a DependencyProperty?

Comment: Yes you should be able to bind out to your DataContext through by using RelativeSource to either the window or usercontrol hosting your button then prefixing the property with DataContext., ie. DataContext.TheProperty.  And no, that property in your DataContext does not need to be a Dependency Property but if the value changes, it will need to NotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll really need to access your control template properties.  Since `Button` already has border properties, you ought to just set those properties on the button directly.  Then, add the border to your `ControlTemplate`, binding its properties to that of the button.